# How to Convert string into XML format

Tags: c#, xml

How can I convert this string into XML?

```
string sTemp = "<message>
 <Category>
   <Category ID=""null|1"" Category Name=""null|SampleCategory1""/>
   <Category ID=""null|2"" Category Name=""null|SampleCategory2""/> 
 <Category/>
 <ProductDetails  Type=""PDF|SWF|DOC|PPT|XLS|HTML|STREAMING"" Status=""Activated|Expired"" Version=""1.0""   FilePathURL=""http://test.mylytica.com/Uploads/PPPC.pdf"" ProductDescription=""null|Text"" VersionDescription=""null|Text"" Author=""null|authorname"" Validity=""null|date|NeverExpiry"" > 
 </ProductDetails >
</message>
";
```

Comment: btw, your XML isn't valid -> http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `XElement.Parse`

```
var element = XElement.Parse(sTemp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `XmlDocument`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

and its `Load` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I like using XDocument, it has a lot of nice functionality for creating and editing xml documents.  It also gives some nice access to the Linq statments for getting the information out without having to loop through all the elements.

```
try
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
}
catch(Exception _ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(_ex.Message);
}
```